# Reason for using protected inheritance in std:: containers

Tags: c++, inheritance, std

The [GCC implementation of `std::vector`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_vector.h) is similar to the following code:

```
#include <memory>

template<
  typename T,
  typename Allocator
  > struct vector_base {

  using T_alloc = typename std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::template rebind_alloc<T>;
  using pointer = typename std::allocator_traits<T_alloc>::pointer;

  struct vector_imp
      : public T_alloc {

    pointer m_start;
    pointer m_finish;
    pointer m_end_of_storage;

    vector_imp()
        : m_start(), m_finish(), m_end_of_storage() { }

    vector_imp(const T_alloc& a)
        : T_alloc(a), m_start(), m_finish(), m_end_of_storage() { }

    // move constructor and swap defined here...
  };

  vector_imp m_imp; // the sole member of vector_base

  // methods for allocating/deallocating and creating storage;
  // destructor.

};

// this class is the "actual" std::vector which you instantiate via
// std::vector<T> x;
template<
  typename T,
  typename Allocator = std::allocator<T>
  > class vector
    : protected vector_base<T, Allocator> {
  // all the interface is implemented in terms of calls to vector_imp;
  // this class has no members (except, of course, from the member of
  // vector_base<T, Allocator>)
};
```

In essence, the API is implemented in terms of a base class and an implementation class. The implementation class contains the three indispensable members: begin of storage, end of data, and end of storage.

I understand why `vector_imp` derives from `T_alloc`: empty base optimization will ensure that stateless allocators will not take any space in a `std::vector`.

However, I don't understand why `vector` uses protected inheritance of `vector_base`. I would have expected it to be private inheritance: nobody needs to know that `vector<T, A>` is *implemented in terms of* `vector_base<T, A>`, not even classes derived from `vector<T, A>`, because it is not meant to be subclassed.

Could you provide an explanation for this design choice?

Answer (score 2):

I doubt there is any reasonable explanation for this. This protected inheritance can be dated back to the original SGI STL implementation - arguably the very first one? May be back than someone thought that after all there would be classess which inherit from vector, probably, ones included in the library.

It didn't happen (as far as I know, at least - there are no descendants of vector in stdcxx Standard Library implementation), but probably no one was interested in changing this inheritance specifier.